# Managing plash Screen in Worklight 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server, worklight-studio

We want to display animated splash screen in MobileFirst 7.1. How can we achieve this? It seems that it does not support by MF 7.1

Secondly,

How can we disable default splash screen display mechanism in MobileFirst 7.1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Animated splash screens are not supported in IBM MobileFirst 7.1

To disable default splash screen or showing a custom splashscreen refer to [Managing splash screen](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen.html)

Comment: can we disable MF 7.1 from showing default splashScreen

Comment: Use WL.App.hideSplashScreen() method to hide the splash screen